# Validating an attribute to be an integer only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

product.rb model file:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :price
  validates_numericality_of :stock, if: Proc.new { |p| (p.stock.is_a? Integer and p.stock >= 0) ? true : false }

  def price=(input)
    input.delete!("$")
    super
  end
end
```

I want stock to be integer only. When I submit stock with float value say 34.48 then in Insert sql cmd in server log, I see 34 only, and it doesn't hit the validation condition above, how is this possible that the validation condition is being true even i send float number.(new to rails, hoping this question makes sense).

Comment: You're misusing `if` parameter. Also, you should use `&&` instead of `and`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The functionality already exists to check for an integer in [`validates_numericality_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_numericality_of) - just set `:only_integer` to `true`

You can use the validation in your active record models as per the [rails documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality).

```
validates :your_column_name, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

Comment: What if the value is not required tho? Null is not a number/integer and therefore I always get a validation error.

Comment: Okaaaaay... `allow_blank: true` does the job `validates :age, numericality: { only_integer: true }, allow_blank: true`